# Converting working ModelBuilder to Python script reports errors in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, syntaxerror

I want to learn Python and ArcPy by converting ModelBuilder to Python script.

First, I tried to use 'extract by mask' in this way.But it failed.

[image]

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Generated by ArcGIS ModelBuilder on : 2022-07-03 01:56:39
"""
import arcpy
def #  NOT  IMPLEMENTED# Function Body not implemented

def Model1():  # Model

# To allow overwriting outputs change overwriteOutput option to True.
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = False

# Check out any necessary licenses.
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

tif = "D:\\04.crash\\tif"
sd_shp = "D:\\04.crash\\shp\\sd.shp"

for fa_tif, Name in #  NOT  IMPLEMENTED(tif, "", "", "NOT_RECURSIVE"):

    # Process: Extract by Mask (Extract by Mask) (sa)
    Name = "fa"
    new_Name_ = fr"D:\04.crash\newtif\new{Name}"
    Extract_by_Mask = new_Name_
    new_Name_ = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(in_raster=fa_tif, in_mask_data=sd_shp)
    new_Name_.save(Extract_by_Mask)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Global Environment settings
    with arcpy.EnvManager(scratchWorkspace=r"D:\test\MyProject.gdb", workspace=r"D:\test\MyProject.gdb"):
        Model1()
```

[image]

```
  File "<string>", line 6
    def #  NOT  IMPLEMENTED# Function Body not implemented
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It seems that the line of `def #  NOT  IMPLEMENTED# Function Body not implemented` is wrong, but I don't konw how to fix it.

However, click 'Run' of ModelBuilder is OK in ArcGIS Pro.

I tried to write some code after reading the code samples of esri.But it still failed. And the error suggests **"invalid pointer"**

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

# Set the current workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/04.crash/tif"

# Get and print a list of tifs from the workspace
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "tif")

# Get the shp
shp = r"D:/04.crash/shp/sd.shp"

# Loop
for raster in rasters:
    outExtractByMask = ExtractByMask(raster, shp)
    outExtractByMask.save("D:/04.crash/newtif")
```

[image]

Comment: Start from scratch and: [ListRasters](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/arcpy/functions/listrasters.htm#C_GUID-5467F0DC-B58F-4DD4-9895-32ADE3F3DE48), for each raster [Extract by mask](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/extract-by-mask.htm). Look at the code samples. Probably easier than fixing the exported code

Comment: Thank for your advice! But why converting ModelBuilder to Python script reported errors? I want to know why.

Comment: Iterators don't export into python. So any looping logic and inline substitution won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ModelBuilder as a way to "learn" Python is sometimes a good idea, other times a bad idea. While it's great to get you started, there is only so much it can cover. You've discovered that exporting a model to a Python script **does not** re-create the iterators. See this [section of help](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/exporting-a-model-to-python.htm).

> Model tools Iterators, Utilities, or Logical tool will not be exported
> to Python. You will need to add equivalent Python functionality that
> these tools provide. For example, you will need to use if/else logic
> to perform conditional branching in your script.

The code you provide (which is erroring):
`for fa_tif, Name in #  NOT  IMPLEMENTED(tif, "", "", "NOT_RECURSIVE"):` is simply starter code that you need to finish. It looks like in the edit you made to your post, based on comments, you discovered that `arcpy.ListRasters` would work as the generator for your script.

Per your second question, and why is it erroring? It looks like it *should* work, my only guess is that you haven't updated your output name and the code is continually trying to overwrite the output
`outExtractByMask.save("D:/04.crash/newtif")`

You'd need to do something like the following to update the name of the new raster:

```
import os
for raster in rasters:
    outputName = os.path.basename(raster)
    outExtractByMask = ExtractByMask(raster, shp)
    outExtractByMask.save("D:/04.crash/newtif_{}".format(outputName))
```